# UIView subview won't get added. UIView won't move. Nothing works

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, size-classes

I have a UIView with a UILabel on top of it. When I switch the size in the storyboard to 'any' (the small box) the label disappears. I can add it again, but when I switch to 'w Compact h Regular' and switch back it's gone again. In the simulator the UILabel isn't there. How do I show the UILabel?

Any:

[image: Any]

Compact Regular:

[image: Compact Regular]

Comment: can you add screenshot on storyboard for "any" and "compact-regular", maybe constraint on left margin (leading space) is too long

Comment: And where is the problem? The screen looks right

Comment: The label doesn't show up in the simulator, and a few times it's even disappeared in the storyboard depending on which size class I chose.

Comment: Why are you changing size classes? Is it something that you absolutely need to do?

Comment: Have you tried the view debugger?

Comment: @Fogmeister I did it once and I don't know how to go back to just using the box. I searched and found nothing. In any case, it doesn't show up even if I have the label showing in the box size class.

Comment: @Fogmeister I tried the view debugger just there. The UILabel is nowhere to be seen although it shows up in the debug navigator.

Comment: Has the UIView correct constraints?

Comment: @ale00 Yes, it does.